# When disconnects from ssh, my Hyperledger Besu nodes stop working

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-besu

I have an Ubuntu server running with a Hyperledger Besu node working, but if I disconnect from the server, my best nodes stop working, and I have to start all nodes again.

How can I do to my Besu nodes keep running always? even if I got disconnected from ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Bezu Nodes as services.

Example:

1. Create service /vol/hbesu/node2/besu-node2.service:

   ```
   [Unit]
    Description=Besu client
    DefaultDependencies=no
    After=syslog.target network.target
    [Service]
    User=admin-besu
    Group=admin-besu
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/local/besu-21.1.0-RC1/bin/besu --data-path=/vol/hbesu/node2/data --bootnodes=enode://ae70183
    KillMode=process
    KillSignal=SIGINT
    TimeoutStopSec=90
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=5s
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

sudo cp /vol/hbesu/node2/besu-node2.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/

2. Start service:

   sudo systemctl daemon-reload

   sudo systemctl enable besu-node2.service

   sudo systemctl start besu-node2.service

   sudo systemctl status -l besu-node2.service